# I messed up the update process from 19.10 to 20.04

Tags: upgrade, 19.10, 20.04

I did `do-release-upgrade -dc` to check if I get 20.04 (I didn't get it without -d) and I go it, so I ran `do-release-upgrade -d` and all was fine. But then I cancelled the download of the packages because my internet was too bad and I decided to do somewhere else at a different time. When I had better internet, `do-release-upgrade -d` gave me "Install all updates before updating".  BUT my system was already on the fossa repos. I checked, no option to bypass that, so okay, `apt full-upgrade`. That errored and said I should do `apt --fix-broken install` and it was fixed. So another `apt full-upgrade` to finish updating. Then I wanted to do `do-release-upgrade -d` again but my system is already an fossa. Can I leave it in this state (debian updates like this, so I assume it's okay) or should I do some post-install steps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to:

1. Ensure that you do not have *eoan* in the *sources.list*s by something like

   ```
   grep "^deb.*eoan" -r /etc/apt/ --include="*.list"
   ```

   Change all *eoan* to *focal* by hand or by

   ```
   cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d
   sudo sed -i "s/eoan/focal/" some.list
   ```
2. Get fresh package lists

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
3. Get all newest dependencies for current release

   ```
   sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
   ```